# Preview image not shwing up after cropping with jcrop

Tags: php, jquery, image, upload, jcrop

I have created a new way of uploading my images using two different php pages.

1 does the uploading while thye other does the cropping. Inpart it seems to work to an extent I had to set permissions on the folder it was saving to and it seemed to work but know it does not for some strange reason. It suppose to save a copy of the cropped image to the same folder but it does not seem to do that at the moment. I have no idea why it worked and has stopped working. I have been looking at the code for a while but for the life of me can't see the problem I am reletively new to php but it seems to be a solution to being able to upload images and crop them wether you are using IE 8,9 or the other browsers.

Here is the code for the upload.php section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C// XHHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTML/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</head>
<body >
<?php
    $folder = 'imgtest/';
    $orig_w = 500;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
        $imageFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $filename = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageFile);

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
        $orig_h = ($height/$width) * $orig_w;

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w,$orig_h);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $orig_w,$orig_h,$width,$height);

        imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.$filename, 100);

        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);

        $filename = urlencode($filename);
        header("Location: crop.php?filename=$filename&height=$orig_h");

    }

?>
    <h1>php Upload Form</h1>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
     <label for="image">Image:</label>
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image!"/>
    </p>
  </form>

</body>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

and here is the code for the crop section :

```
    <?php

$folder = 'imgtest/';
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$orig_w = 500;
$orig_h = $_GET['height'];

$targ_w = 120;
$targ_h = 100;

$ratio = $targ_w / $targ_h;

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($folder.$filename);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'], $targ_w, $targ_h, $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);

    imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.'t_'.$filename, 100);

    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);

    echo "<h1> Saved Thumbnail</h1> <img src=\"$folder/t_$filename\"/>";
}
```

?>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C// XHHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTML/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>php crop form</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js" ></script>

         <link  rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css"  type="text/css"/>

    <style type="text/css">
         #preview
         {
                width: <?php echo $targ_w?>px;
                height:<?php echo $targ_h?>px;
                overflow:hidden;
         }

    </style>
</head>
<body >
  <h1>Jcrop Plugin Behavior</h1>

  <table>
  <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="<?php echo $folder.$filename?>" id="cropbox" alt="cropbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
                Thumb  Preview:

                <div id="preview">
                    <img src="<?php echo $folder.$filename?>" alt="thumb" />
                </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="post">
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Crop Image!"/>
  </p>

  </form>


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                aspectRatio: <?php echo $ratio?>,
                setSelect:[0,0,<?php echo $orig_w.','.$orig_h;?>],
                onSelect:updateCoords,
                onChange:updateCoords
            });
        }); 

        function updateCoords(c)
        {
            showPreview(c);
           $("#x").val(c.x);
           $("#y").val(c.y);
           $("#w").val(c.w);
           $("#h").val(c.h);
        }

        function showPreview(coords)
        {
            var rx =<?php echo $targ_w;?> / coords.w
            var ry =<?php echo $targ_h;?> / coords.h

            $("#preview img").css({
                width: Math.round(rx*<?php echo $orig_w;?>)+'px',
                height: Math.round(ry*<?php echo $orig_h;?>)+'px',
                marginLeft: '-' + Math.round (rx*coords.x)+'px',
                marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry*coords.y)+'px'
            });
        }

</script>
</html>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Headers(in this case location php headers) have to be sent before **any** content already echoed. So move your php part in your `upload.php` to top of that file:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'imgtest/';
    $orig_w = 500;

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
        $imageFile = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $filename = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageFile);

        $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
        $orig_h = ($height/$width) * $orig_w;

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w,$orig_h);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,0,0, $orig_w,$orig_h,$width,$height);

        imagejpeg($tmp, $folder.$filename, 100);

        imagedestroy($tmp);
        imagedestroy($src);

        $filename = urlencode($filename);
        header("Location: crop.php?filename=$filename&height=$orig_h");

    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C// XHHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/XHTML/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</head>
<body >
    <h1>php Upload Form</h1>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
     <label for="image">Image:</label>
     <input type="file" name="image" id="image"/><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image!"/>
    </p>
  </form>

</body>
<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Tell if its still not working.

Comment: Just tried it now and put it on the top but it still does not seem to work.In it just shows either image place holders if I can call them that in IE and in firefox it shows just the alt text.

Comment: You haven't setted php variables in your image showing page (`<img src="<?php echo $folder.$filename?>" alt="thumb" />`). Could it be the problem?

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean. I followed a tutorial and the person said to put it that way.

Comment: Do I have to do something with the PHP.INI to get it to work?

Comment: No, i don't think so. Where you have defined those php variables in your crop page? Because i don't see they defined anywhere in that page...

Comment: $folder = 'imgtest/';
 $filename = $_GET['filename'];
is that not defining them??

Comment: Yea, but that is in your upload page, not **crop** page.

Comment: Nope that is in my crop.php page.
my upload.php page has just $folder = 'imgtest/'; and  $filename = basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); in it.

Comment: no error messages and even when I try to debug it it does not seem to break in to the code.